# Equivalent definition of continuity, unif.continuity, equicontinuity, etc

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

I am trying to summarize some definitions regarding the different types of continuity I know, in my own words, and I would like to know if you think they are correct (that is, if they are equivalent to the definitions you know of these terms)

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces, $(f_i)_{i \in I} \subseteq Y^X$ a family of functions.  Let $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $D(f_i,x,\epsilon)$ be the suprem of the $\delta \geq 0$ such that

$$ f_i(B(x, \delta)) \subseteq B(f_i(x), \epsilon) $$

Note that if $f_i$ is not continuous in $x$ then $D(f_i,x,\epsilon) = 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ (in this case there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that there is no $\delta > 0$ such that $f_i$ is continuous at $x$.)

Note also that $\delta = 0$ satisfies the condition for all $f_i, x, \epsilon$

1) If $ D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)$ **the function $f_i$ is continuous at $x$**

2) If $ D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall x \in X)$ **the function $f_i$ is continuous**

3) If $ D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall i \in I)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is continuous at $x$**

4) If $ D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall i \in I)(\forall x \in X)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is continuous**

5) If $\sup_{x \in X} D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)$ **the function $f_i$ is uniformly continuous**

6) If $\sup_{x \in X} D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall i \in I)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is uniformly continuous**

7) If $\sup_{i \in I} D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is equicontinuous at $x$**

8) If $\sup_{i \in I} D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)(\forall x \in X)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is equicontinuous**

9) If $\sup_{x \in X, i \in I} D(f_i,x,\epsilon) > 0 \ (\forall \epsilon > 0)$ **the family $(f_i)$ is uniformly equicontinuous**

I am not even sure if 1) is correct.  What do you think?

Comment: As far as I can see, all of that makes sense and looks reasonable. I would probably use slightly different notation and move the quantifiers before the "statement" but that's minor. I think some of the last definitions are less standard. But I'm not sure how to help. I could prove some equivalence if you provide two different definition of something, but that you could probably do as well.

Comment: I suspect that 5) implies that if $f_i$ is continuos at $x_0$ then $f_i$ is uniformly continuous even if $f_i$ is discontinuous at some other points.

Comment: What is $x_0$?  As I understand 5) given any $\epsilon > 0$ one could choose any $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta < \sup_{x \in X} D(f_i,x,\epsilon)$ and that $\delta$ works for any $x \in X$, so $f_i$ is continuous in every $x \in X$, in fact uniformly.